# 403B vesting and giving notice

Tags: united-states, employment, 403b, vesting

I have a 403B account that would become fully vested in March. I also have an opportunity to take a new job. If I gave notice before the vestment, but continued working through the vestment date, would I definitely get vested or could they refuse if I give notice?

Comment: The next time you ask a question like this, you may want to take greater care not to identify yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They could let you go immediately, and you would not be vested. Even though you're trying to do the right thing by giving notice, it's safer to stay silent until you're vested, then quit.

Comment: You could lose more than your 403(b) by failing to give proper notice - you could lose your professional reputation. The best thing to do is wait until you are fully vested, then give notice, then two weeks later leave the company.